# How to update a dll inside GAC (MSIL folder)?

Tags: asp.net

I need to update `System.Web.Entity.dll` in the GAC @`C:\Windows\assembly`.
Where can I find the latest dll and how to install it? Can anyone provide guidance on this?

Comment: You cannot. GAC allows you to install multiple versions of the same assembly, so if you install a new version and does not want an old version, you must remove the old version. Of course, that can lead to assembly loading exceptions, which you might or might not be able to fix via assembly redirection. You have to learn GAC and `gacutil` more.

Comment: @LexLi - To clarify,I need to install a new version of the mentioned dll,how can  I do that?please provide specific guidance